# How to auto-increment a field in my class when I declare and initialize an object of the class?

Tags: java, class

I have 3 classes in my Java application, One representing a Medical Policy:

```
public class MedicalPolicy implements PolicyType {
    private int id;
    // and some other fields

    public MedicalPolicy(final LocalDate effective,final LocalDate expiry,final ArrayList<Beneficiary> beneficiaries){
          //Constructor that does NOT set/initialize the id field
    }
}
```

Another class which represents the Motor Policy:

```
public class MotorPolicy implements  PolicyType{

    private int id;
    // and some other fields

    public MotorPolicy(final LocalDate effective,final LocalDate expiry,final double vehiclePrice){
        //Constructor that does NOT set/initialize the id field
    }
}
```

And the 3rd class contains the `main()` method.

Every time I declare and initialize a Medical Policy object in my `main()` I want the `id` of the Medical Policy to increment by 1, the same for the Motor Policy, i.e if I declare 2 Medical Policy objects in my `main()` I want the value of 1st Medical Policy to have the `id` equal to 1 and the 2nd Medical Policy to have the `id`'s value set to 2, and if I declare 3 Motor Policy, I want the 1st to have it's `id` equal to 1, the 2nd's `id` equal to 2 and the 3rd's `id` equal to 3.

How can I accomplish that?

P.S: There is no prob if I have to set/initialize it from the constructor, what's important is that I shouldn't pass it's value as a constructor parameter.

Comment: In both classes: declare a `private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();`, call `counter.getAndIncrement();` in the constructor.

Comment: @Turing85 why should it be final? doesn't final mean that it can't be changed?

Comment: No, `final` means that the reference cannot be reassigned. Its semantics are different from `const` in C/C++

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have suggested in my comment, I would add an [`AtomicInteger`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html) to count the number of constructor calls:

```
public class MedicalPolicy implements PolicyType {
    private static final AtomicInteger counter = new AtomicInteger();

    private final int id;

    public MedicalPolicy(
            final LocalDate effective,
            final LocalDate expiry,
            final ArrayList<Beneficiary> beneficiaries){
        id = counter.incrementAndGet();
    }
}
```

The reason for using an `AtomicInteger` is thread-safety.

Notice, however, that this implementation does only count how often the constructor was called. To get a count of reachable instances of a given class there are two solutions coming to my mind. One involves overriding [`finalize()`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/Object.html#finalize()) (which is deprecated in Java 13). The other uses a `List` of [`PhantomReference`s](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/13/docs/api/java.base/java/lang/ref/PhantomReference.html) to track reachable instances.

Comment: To be honest I didn't understand what you mean by "reachable instances", to be able to initialize an instance of a (non static) class I have to use a constructor.

Comment: Java has a garbage collector. The garbage collector will figure out when objects are no longer needed and destory them. This counter is not able to "see" when objects are destroyed.

Answer (score 1):

Use a `private static int` as an instance variable

Inside the constructor you set the id to the serial and add one to the serial.

```
public class MedicalPolicy implements PolicyType {
    private static int serial = 1;
    private int id;
    // and some other fields

    public MedicalPolicy(final LocalDate effective,
                         final LocalDate expiry,
                         final ArrayList<Beneficiary> beneficiaries){
      this.id = serial++;
      // Other constructor stuff
    }
}
```

If your class needs to be thread safe, use an `AtomicInteger` as Turing85 mentioned.

Comment: It is working fine for me. But I cannot get why it is working :) Why serial is not reset to 1 every time we create a new object instance?

Comment: @pyfyc That's because it's `static`. It belongs to the entire class. All instances share this same variable. See [Understanding Class Members](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/classvars.html).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [AtomicInteger](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/atomic/AtomicInteger.html), which is used in applications such as atomically incremented counters.

```
public class MedicalPolicy implements PolicyType {
  private static final AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(); 
    // and some other fields

    public MedicalPolicy(final LocalDate effective,final LocalDate expiry,final ArrayList<Beneficiary> beneficiaries){
          //Constructor that does NOT set/initialize the id field
         count.incrementAndGet(); 
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Could you not create a List, then each object of that class would be associated to its incrementing location in the index. eg. listName.get(obj num-1) since the first object will be stored at index of 0. Also listName.size() would return a value so you could track how many you had.

Comment: If you hold references to all instances of a class, ever created, you basically write the java-version of a memory leak. Given enough time (and enough constructor invocations of that class), the programm will exit with an `OutOfMemoryException`.